I have problems with version Xcode
when I updated the Xcode to version 16 it has many problems
one of the problems this I tried to solve it but it's working
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_messaging.FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin':
'/Users/mashaelsaud/Documents/mobile-app/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h'
/Users/mashaelsaud/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-15.1.2/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.h:11:8
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.

I solved this problem by following these steps:

Open xcode (your project's ios folder or ios/Runner.xcworkspace)
Select Runner
Tap on Build Settings
Find "Apple clang - Language - Modules" or you can just search "allow"
You will see

Allow non-modular Includes In Framework Modules - NO

Change this to "YES"

Then try to run your app again.

It's working thank you

I'm glad the solution worked for you! If you found the answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you could upvote it to help others as well. Thanks!
